# What is the general name for a surface of form $z = f(x, y)$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is there a generic, geometrical name for a "sheet" of data, where the data fits the form:

$$z = f(x, y)$$

Note that $z$ might be an actual third dimension (such as elevation in terrain data) or any scalar measurement (such as surface temperature).

I know you could generically say "it is a surface"... but a sphere or a cube also are surfaces, and I want to exclude them (from the term I'm looking for) because they are not single-valued in $f(x, y)$.

Note I'm not trying to get too picky that the surface is continuous in $(x, y)$ or discrete.  The dataset might be infinite in range, or only exist for some constrained region in $(x, y)$.  And I'm not concerned if the surface is continuously differentiable.  I'm looking for the term that glosses over all those.

I realize this is might just be called "planar data".  And in some contexts (e.g. terrain maps in video games) I think this may be called "two-and-a-half dimensional data".

But is there a well-established term in *geometry* or *topology* for this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I finally stumbled across the term I was looking for: "[scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field)".  Perhaps this term is more common in physics than math; since my application is in the physical sciences (terrain elevation and radio propagation measurements) I'm probably going to use that in my work.

I really appreciate all who replied.

Answer (score 5):

A map of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)
\longmapsto
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $z=f(x,y)$, which allows a parameterization of the surface
determined by the graph of the function $f$, is called **Monge's chart**.
It is needed that this map be injective and differentiable with domain an open set of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Given any function $F : X \to Y$, the set $$\operatorname{graph}(f) := \{(x, F(x)) : x \in X\} \subseteq X \times Y$$
is called the **graph** of $F$. (Sometimes this is denoted $\Gamma(F)$.) In particular, if $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and $f$ is a function $\Omega \to \Bbb R$, then we can identify $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ with $$\{(x, y, z) : (x, y) \in \Omega, z = f(x, y)\} \subset \Bbb R^3 .$$

The term graph is not specific to geometry or topology, but note that if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, we can ask whether a function $F: X \to Y$ is continuous; either way, $\operatorname{graph}(F)$ inherits a natural topology, namely the subspace topology induced by the product topology on $X \times Y$.

Answer (score 3):

Non-parametric or graph form are two commonly employed words.